# Cartesian product of two sets with smooth boundary

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded sets with smooth boundary. Does the open and bounded set $A \times B$ have (piecewise) smooth boundary? If so can one write the outer unit normal of $A \times B$ as $(n_A,n_B)$?

Comment: So what happens when $A$ and $B$ are open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: then it works since i only want $A \times B$ to have a piecewise smooth boundary.

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "smooth" boundary. If you want it to be a smooth embedding of the boundary into $\Bbb R^{2n}$, then no. Just consider $A = B = (0,1)$. The boundary of $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ is well-known for having four points where it is not smoothly embedded.